# vim visual block search/replace only replacing first occurrence on a line

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I'm trying the following command in visual mode to attempt a global find/replace on a block of text

> :'<,'>s/red/green/g

The text looks like this

> red red red blue red red red blue

And the result

> green red red blue red red red blue

Instead of what I am expecting with the **g** switch:

> green green green blue green green green blue

Any idea what causes this behaviour? If it is default behaviour how do I make **g** really *really* global?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've probably `:set gdefault`; this inverts the meaning of the `g` substitution flag. You can check where it got set via `:verbose set gdefault?` and temporarily turn it off via `:set nogdefault`, but you probably want to find the place where it got set and remove it from there.

Comment: Thank you! It was set in my .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my vim and get the correct result as:

```
green green green blue green green green blue
```

Maybe there is something in your .vimrc changing the default behavior. Would you like to attach it to this thread?